# How to fix 'Reply already submitted error' in flutter?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I'm using flutter v1.7.8+hotfix.3. I'm creating new users and adding their details on firestore database. When I add a user for the first time, it works fine. When I try to add another new user, I get the following error and the app crashes:

> E/CloudFirestorePlugin(11070): Timed out waiting for Task
>   E/CloudFirestorePlugin(11070): java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException:
>   Timed out waiting for Task E/CloudFirestorePlugin(11070):     at
>
> > com.google.android.gms.tasks.Tasks.await(Unknown Source:32) E/CloudFirestorePlugin(11070):   at
> >     io.flutter.plugins.firebase.cloudfirestore.CloudFirestorePlugin$4.apply(Cl>oudFirestorePlugin.java:409)
> >     E/CloudFirestorePlugin(11070):    at
> >     io.flutter.plugins.firebase.cloudfirestore.CloudFirestorePlugin$4.apply(Cl>oudFirestorePlugin.java:361)
> >     E/CloudFirestorePlugin(11070):    at
> >     com.google.firebase.firestore.FirebaseFirestore.lambda$runTransaction$1(co>m.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@@19.0.0:283)
> >     E/CloudFirestorePlugin(11070):    at
> >     com.google.firebase.firestore.FirebaseFirestore$$Lambda$3.call(Unknown
> >     Source:6) E/CloudFirestorePlugin(11070):     at >com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzv.run(Unknown Source:2) E/CloudFirestorePlugin(11070):   at
> >     java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:>1167)
> >     E/CloudFirestorePlugin(11070):    at
> >     java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java>:641)
> >     E/CloudFirestorePlugin(11070):    at
> >     java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764) D/AndroidRuntime(11070): Shutting down VM E/AndroidRuntime(11070): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
> >     E/AndroidRuntime(11070): Process: com.example.task_manager, PID: 11070
> >     E/AndroidRuntime(11070): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Reply
> >     already >submitted E/AndroidRuntime(11070):   at
> >     io.flutter.embedding.engine.dart.DartMessenger$Reply.reply(DartMessenger.j>ava:135)
> >     E/AndroidRuntime(11070):  at
> >     io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodChannel$IncomingMethodCallHandler$1.error(M>ethodChannel.java:230)
> >     E/AndroidRuntime(11070):  at
> >     io.flutter.plugins.firebase.cloudfirestore.CloudFirestorePlugin$3.onComple>te(CloudFirestorePlugin.java:427)
> >     E/AndroidRuntime(11070):  at
> >     com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzj.run(Unknown Source:4) E/AndroidRuntime(11070):  at
> >     android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873) E/AndroidRuntime(11070):     at
> >     android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) E/AndroidRuntime(11070):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
> >     E/AndroidRuntime(11070):  at
> >     android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669) E/AndroidRuntime(11070):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native
> >     Method) E/AndroidRuntime(11070):     at >com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.ja>va:493)
> >     E/AndroidRuntime(11070):  at
> >     com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858) I/Process (11070): Sending signal. PID: 11070 SIG: 9 Application
> >     finished.

I'm using following code to add a new user:

```
 _sendToServer() {

    if (_formKey.currentState.validate()) {
      //No error in validator
      _formKey.currentState.save();     
        Firestore.instance.runTransaction((Transaction transaction) async {
          DocumentReference reference =
              Firestore.instance.collection('Users').document(_name);
          await transaction.get(reference);

          await reference.setData({
            "Name": "$_name",
            "Email": "$_email",
            "Password": "$_password",
            "status": "new",
            "clientName": widget.title
          });
        });    
      registerUser();
    }
  }

  registerUser() async {
    String userId =
        await widget.auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(_email, _password);
    if (_formKey.currentState.validate()) {
      //No error in validator
      _formKey.currentState.save();
        Firestore.instance.runTransaction((Transaction transaction) async {
          DocumentReference reference =
              Firestore.instance.collection('UserRoles').document(_name);
          await transaction.get(reference);

          await reference
              .setData({"userid": "$userId", "role": "user", "status": "new"});
        });
        Navigator.pop(context);
        Navigator.push(
            context,
            MaterialPageRoute(
                builder: (context) => AdminPage(
                      auth: widget.auth,
                      onSignedOut: widget.onSignedOut,
                      title: widget.title,
                    )));
    }
  }
```

I have tried using flutter clean. But it works only for one time.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Per checking this [bug](https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire/issues/951), the issue should be already fixed as of the current version of cloud_firestore (2.5.3 as of this writing). This issue was previously reproducible by subscribing to a DocumentReference's snapshots.